# Is there a way to create one array properties with many mongoDB objectiID inside

Tags: arrays, mongodb, model, objectid, loopback4

I use Loopback4.
When i want to add a mongoDb ObjectId property inside my model i do that :

```js
    @property({
        type: 'string',
        mongodb: {dataType: 'ObjectID'},
    })
    organizationId?: string;
```

Now i want to make an array with MongoDB ObjectId properties inside, so i tried to do :

```js
    @property({
        type: 'array',
        itemType: 'string',
        mongodb: {dataType: 'ObjectID'},
    })
    tagsId?: string[];
```

but it seems like all the array is converted to one ObjectID inside the mongoDb.

What I want to do is to simply get **an array with many ObjectId inside**. I tried everything in my knowledgme: that was not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution : 
Step 1 : 
create a model with just one id.
Step 2 : 
Make an array with your new model

Step 1 : 
In your future model (in my case : tagReference) :

```js
@model()
export class TagReference extends Entity {
    @property({
        type: 'string',
        mongodb: {dataType: 'ObjectID'},
    })
    id?: string;

    constructor(data?: Partial<TagReference>) {
        super(data);
    }
}
```

Step 2: 
Where you want your array :

```js
import {TagReference} from './tag-reference.model';

@model()
export class Resource extends BaseEntity {

    // ...

    @property({
        type: 'array',
        itemType: TagReference,
    })
    tagIds?: string[];

   // ...
}
```